# RecyclerView creating extra space even when width is matchparent and height is wrap content

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am very confused why my recyclerview has this huge extra space between it. I am still new to design in Android and will appreciate feedback.

Here is my student_layout to be displayed in the `recyclerview`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="74dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="174dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/usernamePaddingTop"
                android:textColor="@color/_black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/usernameTextSize"
                tools:text="Student" />
        </LinearLayout>
        
        <TextView
          
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:textColor="@color/grey"/>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/loginWidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/loginHeight"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/loginPadding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/loginPadding"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/blue_button"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_background" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My MainFragment with a Recyclcer view

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.MainFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/studentlogs"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:listitem="@layout/student_logs_fragment"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

The image on my emulator[image]

Comment: Set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` inside `ConstraintLayout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in student_layout xml file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

You have to try `wrap_parent` instead of `match_parent` in `constraintLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="74dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="174dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/usernamePaddingTop"
                android:textColor="@color/_black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/usernameTextSize"
                tools:text="Student" />
        </LinearLayout>
        
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:textColor="@color/grey"/>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/loginWidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/loginHeight"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/loginPadding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/loginPadding"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/blue_button"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_background" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Replace the code at student_layout